# Jquery dialog text doesn't read html when generated from code behind

Tags: html, jquery, vb.net, jquery-ui-dialog, code-behind

In our project we are calling dialog boxes two ways. For the ones with static text and buttons we generate the dialog in a script and get the text from hidden spans in front-end. When using html elements inside the text from the span (i.e `<br />`), it renders correctly.

But when we create the same setup in code behind, it doesn't interpret the html.

This code works:

```
    var okClicked = false;
    var control;
    
$(".confirmAction").unbind('click');
    $(".confirmAction").click(function (e) {
        var control = $(this);

        let title = $(this).find('.confirmTitle').text();
        let info = $(this).find('.confirmInfo').html();

        if (!title.trim()) {
            title = "Er du sikker?"
        }
        if (!info.trim()) {
            info = "Vennligst bekreft at du vil gjennomføre denne operasjonen."
        }

        if (!okClicked) {
            $("<div class='consioDialogContainer'><i class='fa fa-5x fa-exclamation-triangle consioDialogIcon'></i><h2>" + title + "</h2><p>" + info + "</p></div>").dialog({
                autoOpen: true,
                modal: true,
                dialogClass: 'consioConfirmDialog',
                width: 500,
                minHeight: 300,
                top: '50%',
                left: '50%',
                title: title,
                open: function (event, ui) {
                    $('.consioConfirmDialog').find('.consioButtonCancel').focus();
                },
                buttons: [
                    {
                        text: 'Fortsett',
                        'class': 'consioButtonOK',
                        click: function () {
                            try {
                                showInprogress();
                            }catch (e){
                            }
                            okClicked = true;
                            control.trigger('click');
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                        }
                    }, {
                        text: 'Avbryt',
                        'class': 'consioButtonCancel',
                        click: function () {
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                        }
                    }
                ],
                Close: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
        console.info('We may post back now!!!');
        okClicked = false;
        return true;
    });
```

This one does not:

```
    Private Function BuildScript() As String
        Dim script As New StringBuilder()
        script.AppendLine("<script type=""text/javascript"">")
        script.AppendLine($"    var msgboxResult = ''")
        script.AppendLine($"    function {Me.ClientID}() {{")
        script.AppendLine($"        $('<div class=""consioDialogContainer""><i class=""fas fa-5x {MessageBoxIcon} consioDialogIcon""></i><h2>{MessageBoxTitle}</h2><p>{MessageBoxText.Replace("'", "\'")}</p></div>').dialog({{")
        script.AppendLine($"                modal: true,")
        script.AppendLine($"                title: '{MessageBoxTitle}',")
        script.AppendLine($"                zindex: 10000,")
        script.AppendLine($"                autoOpen: true,")
        script.AppendLine($"                width: '500',")
        script.AppendLine($"                minHeight: 300,")
        script.AppendLine($"                top: '50%',")
        script.AppendLine($"                left: '50%',")
        script.AppendLine($"                dialogClass: '{If(MessageBoxType <> MessageBoxTypeClass.None, MessageBoxType.ToString(), "consioInfoDialog")}',")
        script.AppendLine($"                resizable: false,")
        script.AppendLine($"                open: function (event, ui) {{ $('.{If(MessageBoxType <> MessageBoxTypeClass.None, MessageBoxType.ToString(), "consioInfoDialog")}').find('.{FocusButtonClass()}').focus();}},")
        script.AppendLine($"                buttons: [")
        Select Case MsgBoxButton
            Case VbMsgBoxButton.vbOKOnly
                script.AppendLine(OKButton())
                Exit Select
            Case VbMsgBoxButton.vbOKCancel
                script.AppendLine($"{OKButton()},")
                script.AppendLine(CancelButton())
                Exit Select
            Case VbMsgBoxButton.vbAbortRetryIgnore
                script.AppendLine($"{AbortButton()},")
                script.AppendLine($"{RetryButton()},")
                script.AppendLine(IgnoreButton())
                Exit Select
            Case VbMsgBoxButton.vbRetryCancel
                script.AppendLine($"{RetryButton()},")
                script.AppendLine(CancelButton())
                Exit Select
            Case VbMsgBoxButton.vbYesNo
                script.AppendLine($"{YesButton()},")
                script.AppendLine(NoButton())
                Exit Select
            Case VbMsgBoxButton.vbYesNoCancel
                script.AppendLine($"{YesButton()},")
                script.AppendLine($"{NoButton()},")
                script.AppendLine(CancelButton())
                Exit Select
        End Select
        script.AppendLine($"            ],")
        script.AppendLine($"                close: function(event, ui) {{ $(this).remove();{ExitScript}; }}".Replace(";;", ";"))
        script.AppendLine($"            }});")
        script.AppendLine($"}}")
        'Str = (((((Str() & "       Dim msgboxResult" & ChrW(10) & ChrW(9) & ChrW(9) & "msgboxResult = msgbox(""") & Me.MessageBoxText & """") & Me.BuildMsgboxAttributeConstants) & Me.BuildMsgboxTitle & ")") & ChrW(10) & Me.BuildReturnScript)
        If Me.ShowOnWindowOnload Then
            script.AppendLine($"    jQuery(function($){{")
            script.AppendLine($"        {Me.ClientID}();")
            ' the two lines below removes disabled classes for buttons that, for some reason, looks disabled by default.
            script.AppendLine($"        $('.ui-state-disabled').removeClass('ui-state-disabled');")
            script.AppendLine($"        $('.ui-button-disabled').removeClass('ui-button-disabled');")
            script.AppendLine($"    }});")
        End If
        Return script.AppendLine("</script>").ToString()
    End Function

    Protected Overrides Sub Render(output As HtmlTextWriter)
        If Me.Enabled Then
#Disable Warning BC40000 ' Type or member is obsolete
            Parent.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), ID, BuildScript())
#Enable Warning BC40000 ' Type or member is obsolete
            output.Write(BuildScript())
        End If
    End Sub
```

I have tried a few things with MessageBoxTitle, but none of it matters. I have tried only returning the value without any replaces and I have tried encoding it.

```
Public Property MessageBoxText As String
        Get
            Return _messageBoxText
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            '_messageBoxText = WebUtility.HtmlEncode(value)
            _messageBoxText = value?.Replace("<", "&lt;")?.Replace(">", "&gt;")?.Replace(ChrW(13) & ChrW(10), "<br />")?.Replace(ChrW(10), "<br />")?.Replace(ChrW(13), "<br />")
        End Set
    End Property
```

Basically, everything works as it should when generating the script from behind, except that it doesn't interpret the html tags. So when I add this text:

```
MsgBox("<i>Endringer ikke lagret!<i/> <br>Dere bruker Visma eller et annet system som har begrensinger på antall tegn noen felter kan ha. <br />Følgende felter er for lange: " & res)
```

It doesn't render the italics and line breaks, but shows it as `<i>Endringer ikke lagret!<i/> <br>Dere bruker Visma eller et annet system som har begrensinger på antall tegn noen felter kan ha. <br />Følgende felter er for lange:`.
When I add the same text to the span "confirmInfo" in front-end it renders correctly.

Any suggestions or ideas would be appreciated as I couldn't find anything about this particular case when searching online.

Comment: Your encoding attempting seems to the wrong way - if it's appears as `<` then it's already encoded or being encoded along the line somewhere.  You could try `value?.Replace("&lt;", "<")`.  Possibly in the JS rather than code-behind.   Can you view the rendered script?  It's unclear form [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.htmltextwriter.write?view=netframework-4.8#system-web-ui-htmltextwriter-write(system-string)) if `TextWriter` auto converts HTML to text (ie encodes it) but all the examples show plain text only with HTML as "RenderBeginTag" and similar

Comment: I cannot view the rendered script or debug it unfortunately, but it looks like it is indeed something with encoding. I just don't know how to fix it. 

I compared the two dialogs and on the one who doesn't work the line comes out as 

`<p>&lt;i&gt;Endringer ikke lagret!&lt;i/&gt; &lt;br&gt;Dere bruker Visma eller et annet system som har begrensinger på antall tegn noen felter kan ha. &lt;br /&gt;Følgende felter er for lange: Fornavn (maks 20 karakterer)</p>`

So I tried to use `_messageBoxText = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(value)` instead of the replace, but it doesn't make any difference.